# crypto.X509Store load_locations() do nothing

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, opensc

I want to add trusted certificates from directory. I tried to use:

```
store = crypto.X509Store()
store.load_locations(None, ".\\certificates")
```

and then

```
context = crypto.X509StoreContext(self.store, cert)
```

where cert is my certificate which I want to verify.

It does completely nothing.  I tried to open this directory. I worked. I read those certificates. It worked too. But when I was trying verify my cert by `context.verify_certificate()` it failed. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [documentation for X509StoreContext objects](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509storecontext-objects), you will see that you need to execute either the "get_verified_chain()" or the "verify_certificate()" method in order to do the verification.
So, adding something around those lines should execute your verification :

```
context = crypto.X509StoreContext(self.store, cert)
try:
  checked_chn = store_ctxt.verify_certificate()
except crypto.X509StoreContextError as e:
  print(e)
```